# Cannot install MongoDB in Oracle Linux 8

Tags: mongodb, centos8, oraclelinux

After following the documentation provided here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

I keep getting this error:

> Error:
> Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
>
> - package mongodb-org-5.0.12-1.el8.x86_64 does not have a compatible architecture
> - nothing provides mongodb-org-database needed by mongodb-org-5.0.12-1.el8.x86_64
> - nothing provides mongodb-mongosh needed by mongodb-org-5.0.12-1.el8.x86_64
> - nothing provides mongodb-org-tools needed by mongodb-org-5.0.12-1.el8.x86_64
>   (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

when I try to run

> sudo yum install mongodb-org

Comment: Better better follow [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Red Hat or CentOS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/)

Comment: ya this is the one i followed.. im sorry for proving the wrong link

Comment: Did you carefully follow the instructions? What about [Platform Support](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/#footnote-oracle-linux): *MongoDB only supports Oracle Linux running the Red Hat Compatible Kernel (RHCK). MongoDB does **not** support the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel (UEK).*

Comment: Yes i did, after serval attempts I installed Enterprise edition and its working fine now,